# CSS images not loaded myfaces and primefaces, #{resource['image...']} not working

Tags: css, maven, jsf, primefaces, myfaces

I tried many forum but I didn't found a solution that working to solve my problem.
Currently I am using a Maven project in Eclipse to make a website using myfaces and primefaces. I am also using Apache Tomcat 8.0.28.

Everything in my project works fine except the loading of images from CSS file. I include CSS in my xhtml template files using (between `<h:head></h:head>`) :

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/styles.css"/>
```

My CSS which is under /resources/css is loaded correctly. But not images inside it. I tried these solutions :

```
- background-image: url("#{resource['images/image.jpg']}");
- background: #FFF url(../images/image.jpg);
- background: #FFF url(../images/image.jpg.xhtml); -> works but I don't know why ??
```

The last line is working so in a first time I used that solution but the problem I incountered for my own images has been incountered also with primefaces css images...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ASz3.png)

**Note :** when I use `<h:graphicImage name="images/image.png">` inside xhtml that works !

[Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgAek.png)

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
  <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
  <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
  <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
  <param-value>glass-x</param-value>
</context-param>
<security-constraint>
  <display-name>Security constraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Automatic SLL forwarding</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

My pom.xml :

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
   <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
   <version>5.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.10</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.10</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomahawk20</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.14</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
   <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.10</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <finalName>dnsEnumArtifact</finalName>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
       <source>1.8</source>
       <target>1.8</target>
     </configuration>
   </plugin>
 </plugins>
</build>
```

I don't know where the problem is, configuration, web.xml, dependencies, tomcat...
Thank you in advance for your help.

Laurent

Comment: Try `url("#{resource['images:image.jpg']}")`

Comment: Did you restart the webapp after adding an EL expression to the CSS file for the first time? Namely, JSF will only during a first request check if the CSS contains any EL expressions and if not, then remember it so that it doesn't need to scan and evaluate EL expressions in subsequent requests (which is faster). This is remembered applicationwide and gets only reset when the application is restarted.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers !
- I tried url("#{resource['images:image.jpg']}") but it still not working, images are not loaded.

- When you say restart the webapp, you mean restart tomcat ? When I change something in my project I follow these steps :
   - I empty tomcat cache
   - I empty firefox cache also
   - I rebuild maven project
   - I stop and restart tomcat

I thing you are right EL expressions are not evaluated but I really don't understand why ?...

Thank you in advance.

Laurent